# Open Youtube First Song

Tags: c#, youtube

I realise I haven't researched this much, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction please.

I'm building a C# application, and I want it to open a youtube song when the user requests it.

Does anyone know how to send a search request to the youtube page and get C# to play the first song that comes up?

Comment: I'm not after the exact code - I'm after if youtube search will work in this kind of function.

Comment: "I realise I haven't researched this much". Then do so.

Comment: Yes, you can do this; but not without some more research.

Comment: `I haven't researched this much`, come back when you have then. SO's for code-specific questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your research from youtube api documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Thank you! This is the information I was after...